# Are the Prym varieties geometrcally nondegenerate subvarieties of the Jacobians?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, jacobians, prym-varieties

A subvariety $V$ of an abelian variety $X$ is  *geometrically nondegenerate* if it meets any subvariety of $X$ of  dimension bigger than or equal $codim(V)$.

My question is about the Prym varieties as subvarieties of the Jacobians of curves.  Are they geometrically nondegenerate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pryms are geometrically degenerate.  Let $f:Y\to X$ be an étale double cover of a genus $g>1$ curve $X$.  Up to taking isogenous quotients, which will not affect "geometric degeneracy", the Prym of $f$ is the kernel of $\text{Alb}_f : \text{Alb}_Y\to \text{Alb}_X$, where the domain is an Abelian variety of dimension $2g-1$, and where the target is an Abelian variety of dimension $g$.  The Prym has dimension $g-1$, so codimension $g$ in $\text{Alb}_Y$.  So now let $C\subset \text{Alb}_X$ be any curve that does not contain the origin.  Then the inverse image $\text{Alb}_f^{-1}(C)$ is a subvariety of $\text{Alb}_Y$ of dimension $g$ that is disjoint from the Prym.

Comment: How about cover of degree $r > 2$?

Comment: "How about cover of degree $r>2$?"  It will be the same.  What the argument is actually showing is that every proper sub-Abelian variety (of positive dimension) of an Abelian variety is algebraically degenerate.  For a hypersurface in the quotient Abelian variety that does not contain the origin, the inverse image is a hypersurface that is disjoint from the sub-Abelian variety.